# ArrayOutOfBounds with onresume()?

Tags: android

I have problem with ArrayOutOfBounds. It only happen when i try to resume an activity i have app that when you click on listview it brings you to update page but it said it arrayoutofbounds and i dont know why.

```
populateFields(){

                        arr = getStates.split(",");



                           //monday 
                   if(arr[0] == "true"){
                      states[0] = true;
                   }



                           //tue
                           if(arr[1] == "true"){
                               states[1] = true;
                           } 

                           //wed
                           if(arr[2] == "true"){
                               states[2] = true;
                           }

                           //thur
                           if(arr[3] == "true"){
                               states[3] = true;
                           }

                           //fri
                           if(arr[4] == "true"){
                               states[4] = true;
                           }

                           //sat
                           if(arr[5] == "true"){
                               states[5] = true;
                           }

                           //sun
                           if(arr[6] == "true"){
                               states[6] = true;
                           }


                           else{

                           }}
```

and it said it has problem with:

```
 @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            getDatabaseInfo.open(); 
            setRowIdFromIntent();
            populateFields(); // this line
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of getStates(). It looks like there is something else than you are expecting.